# How can I get the local filesystem path of the public folder for a meteor phonegap app with javascript

Tags: cordova, meteor

In a meteor phonegap app, all the files in /public get downloaded to the device local file system.

On the disk, the public folder path is something like:

```
/Users/abc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/065B5AF8-FE25-4813-8E7D-AA88270DAD88/data/Containers/Data/Application/F73D96BC-EA19-4584-BE52-1D3B3AB8197C/Library/NoCloud/meteor/415e7371b3dc46d1fe41d04a4c4b6cb4ffc40811/
```

I can easily get the bit before '/meteor/' by calling cordova.file.dataDirectory, but how can I get that version kinda id after '/meteor/'? I guess it's some kinda hot code push version number?

I know I can use the file api to read the directory but is there a more elegant way from meteor itself which can provide the same info?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to import but say you want to import a sass file that was part of a package:

```
@import '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionic-sass/ionic';
```

This is a reliable path.

Getting to the public folder would just be

```
./public
```

This will give you the public directory within the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on both iOS and Android.

lets say I want to get a sound file named bell.wav that i've put into my public directory (/public/bell.wav).

```
getLocalPath = function(file) {
    return cordova.file.applicationDirectory.replace('file://', '') + 'www/application/' + file;
};



getLocalPath('bell.wav')
```